# Progressive Refinement Radiosity Algorithm

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I would like to find a detailed description, best with example using OpenGL of Progressive Refinement Radiosity Algorithm, but can't. More precisely, how do you compute the value with which you are supposed to update the radiosities of the gatherer quads, and the unshot power of their parent shooter quads.

I tried reading [GPU gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter39.html), and I think the part I'm searching for is

```
  DE = r * FF * E
  add DE to residual texture
  add DE to radiosity texture
```

But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that's the part that is distributing energy from a source quad to other quads. The FF is a form factor which is a value between 0 and 1.

The form factor takes into account distance and orientation of the quads to determine how much light is received. So for example two very near, opposite facing quads will get a form factor near 1, and two quads with a small angle between their normals, very far away, or both, will get a value near 0.

r would be the differential area between the source quad and the gathering quad. I think r would be 4 if the gather quads area was 4 times bigger than the source quad. You don't need this if your quads are uniform in size (it will just be 1).

E is the energy being shot from the source quad. It's a stored value and isn't calculated when the quad is the source. It's only updated when the quad is gathering.

DE is the amount of E received by a single gather quad.

These two articles are better in my opinion:

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Radiosity_In_English-The_Basics.shtml
http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Radiosity_In_English-Form_Factor_Calculation.shtml